# Simple word count of an input

Tags: java.util.scanner

So I am not an advanced programmer, I am in a Java class, so basically I am trying to stick to the methods and classes that we have learned so far in class... But, ultimately what I am trying to do is create a program that will allow the user to enter a paragraph and count each word as a separate input, and when the word count gets up to 5 it will put the remaining words on a new line...

I haven't gotten to the part where I will put the remaining words on a new line, but for some reason, even when count > 4, the program won't leave the loop...

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleBooleanExpression 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        boolean newLine = count > 4;

        while(!(newLine)) 
        {
            String eachWord = input.next();
            System.out.print(eachWord + " ");
            ++count;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never change `newline` to resolve to `true`. Add `newline = count > 4` in your while loop after you increase `count`, or check if `count>4` and then `break`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try instead of making the `boolean newLine=count > 4`, you could change the while loop statement to `while(count<4)`. This might help. Also, if you want to do the loop 5 times, you might want to change it to `count<5` or `count≤4`. Hope this helps!